# Understanding the many "FROM" addresses that apply to SenderID, DKIM, and SPF

Tags: spf, email-bounces, dkim, email

Can someone tell me **when and why** a client, MTA relay, Unix .Forward, anonymous relay, or listserver will create, or alter these headers:

- Resent-Sender:
- Resent-From:
- Sender:
- From:

If you can please include a software version, or an example of software that alters any of those fields.

Finally is it correct to say that the Purported Responsible Address is "dynamic"? ([see page 13 here](http://www.maawg.org/sites/maawg/files/news/MAAWG_Email_Authentication_Paper_2008-07.pdf))

Comment: How could you accept an answer which does not even mention SPF or DKIM?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following information on message headers comes from Microsoft's information on [SenderID](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5546)

**Resent-From**

- This is the preferred header for mailing list software to use. Also the servers that unauthenticated guests use (on a hotel network for example) should post their address here.

**Sender**

- Third party mailing lists, "email this article to a friend", and similar services that send email on behalf of users use this field.
- Most of today's mailing list software already adds a header, usually "Sender, that identifies the owner of the mailing list.

**From:**

- This header is used by default when a user in one domain sends email to a user in another.

**None of the above**

- Unix `.forward` configurations don't change anything within the email and make it impossible to distinguish from a spoofer.  These systems should use the Resent-from header, or Sender header.

In addition to the headers mentioned above, Microsoft proposed a new envelope command called `Mail Submitter` that would work alongside the traditional `Mail from` command

*(This is a Community Wiki Post, please edit or update with correct information as you come across it)*